# ASP.NET message box

Tags: asp.net, messagebox

I am looking for a custom control which could enable me to call message of following type.

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/message-box/msg-box.html

Is there a control which function like a .NET desktop application messagebox?

I know, exactly similar may not be possible but main features I am looking for here is returning value of clicked button and custom value entered by user in code behind.

I have also started working on it myself, but hardly any luck so far.. any direction in this case will also be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

There is a **good tutorial** which could help:

[Create MessageBox user control using ASP.NET and CSS](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/05/28/Create-MessageBox-user-control-using-ASPNET-and-CSS.aspx)

And here combining it with the **AjaxControlToolkit**:

[ASP.NET Popup Message Box User Control](http://beckelman.net/post/2008/07/15/ASPNET-Popup-Message-Box-User-Control.aspx)

*I hope this helps!*

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)? It doesn't do all the things you want, but it should be too hard to the extender and controls needed into a CustomControl and create your own DLL.

Comment: yes i did looked into that but really if it is not so hard to extend, then why I have not found single instance where it is done. I am sure this is not first time someone have faced this problem. Still I even if you could Guide in terms of extending the earlier controls that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

use the namespace "System.Windows.Forms" by adding the reference to the solution explorer