# Messagebox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, messagebox

I need a simple messagebox in asp.net, I tried the following code.

```
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "clientScript","<script>javascript:alert('Guest already associated with 
another event');</script>")
```

but I had no luck. Actually I have a dropdownlist which is in a updatepanel it should throw an error message via a MessageBox. I don't know why javascript not working. Is there any other way by which we could show an simple error message in MessageBox.

Comment: Where is this code called?  Page_Load?

Comment: When do u want to see that alert? After clicking a button or selecting an item in dropdown

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782847/simple-asp-net-messagebox

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET message box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293697/asp-net-message-box)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 static public void DisplayMessage(Control page, string msg)
{
    string myScript = String.Format("alert('{0}');", msg);

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "MyScript", myScript, true);
}



 DisplayMessage(this, "Guest already associated with another event");
```

Comment: The best method I found till date!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
private void MessageboxAnzeigen(string content){
  string Script 
  = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('"
  + content
  + "')</script>";
  RegisterClientScriptBlock("WindowOpener", Script);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this user control which will help you 
[MessageBox Usercontrol with ASP.net](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/05/28/Create-MessageBox-user-control-using-ASPNET-and-CSS.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use this simple way

```
protected string Alert = "";
page_load(sender e ...)
{

     Alert ="<script>alert('hi');</script>";

}
```

and in your aspx file use this code to alert a message

```
<%= Alert %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier:

```
MsgBox("Text")
```

Or:

```
MsgBox("Text", 0, "Title")
```

0 is the number of buttons (0 is 1, 1 is 2...)