# How to include multiple messages in one MsgBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to include multiple messages in one MsgBox using `\n`. I need to remove this string when the MsgBox is shown.

This is my code.

```
Dim Msg As String = ""
Dim EmployeeFirstName As String
Dim EmployeeLastName As String
EmployeeFirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim
EmployeeLastName = txtLastName.Text.Trim
If EmployeeFirstName = "" Then
  Msg = "Please enter First Name!"
  Msg += "/n"
End If
If EmployeeLastName = "" Then
  Msg += "Please enter Last Name!"
  Msg += "/n"
End If
If ddlGender.SelectedItem.Value = -1 Then
  Msg += "Plrase Select department"
  Msg += "/n"
End If
MsgBox(Msg)
```

Comment: Note that you should avoid using MsgBox in asp.net. You may find this doesn't work when you deploy your application as the MsgBox only runs Server side. Have a look at this instead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338630/messagebox-in-asp-net

Comment: What string do you need to remove?  It's worth noting that you say `\n` in your question and then post code that includes `/n`, but in VB you typically need to use the constant `vbCrLf` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` is usually a good choice when you need to build a string dynamically. It often performs better, and generally makes for cleaner, more maintainable code than doing a bunch of string concatenation.

```
Dim msgBuilder As New StringBuilder()
'...
If EmployeeFirstName = "" Then
    msgBuilder.AppendLine("Please enter First Name!")
End If
'And so forth
MsgBox(msgBuilder.ToString())
```

But, as Matt Wilko points out, if this is ASP.NET, you don't want to use MsgBox at all.

Answer (score 1):

Like this ...

```
Msg = "Please enter First Name!" & vbCrlf
Msg &= "Please enter Last Name!" & vbCrlf
Msg &= "Please Select department"
```